# Xcode: Put structured data into Localizable.strings file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, string, cocoa

I have a list of genres from a database.

For each genre, I need to add synonyms specified by the Product team at my company.

For example, `chamber music` is a synonym for `classical`.

So the data provided to me by my product manager is essentially an `NSDictionary` where the keys are the primary genres as `NSString`s, and the values are each an `NSSet` of `NSString` synonyms.

Here's the question: I would like to store this information in `Localizable.strings` along with all the other user facing text in the app. I will need to parse it at runtime to insert the synonyms based on the genres returned from the database.

Is there a standard way I can specify this structured data in a localized strings file? And then I'll need to parse it out into the data structure described above.

Simplest for my Product Manager would probably be to use something like CSV in the strings file, and then parse it by hand at runtime.

So maybe my `Localizable.strings` would have an entry like this:

```
"GenreSynonyms"        = "classical, chamber music, opera\
                          alternative, grunge, indie\
                          spanish, latin, salsa"
```

Is this a reasonable solution to the problem? Does Apple have any recommendation for storing data in a `.strings` file that's not a simple flat list of mappings?

I've reviewed [Apple's programming guide for Strings Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH6) but didn't find anything like this.

---

Update: From Jerome's comment, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521881/878969).

Sounds like localizing an entire plist (the first option described in the answer) may be my best bet.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't do it. But may I suggest you to create a .plist and localize it? you would then be able to retrieve directly a NSDictionary by reading it.

Comment: @JeromeDiaz Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason why you couldn't do it.

But may I suggest you to create a .plist and localize it? You would then be able to retrieve directly a NSDictionary by reading it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a plist file that has a root key with the locale code.

Comment: Any reason this would be preferable to a separate `plist` per locale?

Comment: easier to check if a locale exists by checking for a key than for a file, but it's personal preference.