# Best way to represent un-ordered data in a plist

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I'm making a plist to hold [genre synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916031/xcode-put-structured-data-into-localizable-strings-file). The list of synonyms for a given genre doesn't have any inherent order to it.

Should I use an array (which implies an order that doesn't exist) or a dictionary (which implies there's a corresponding value for each key, which doesn't exist).

Simply put--to store an unordered set in a plist, how should I represent it and why?

(To clarify: If there were a `Set` data structure in the `plist` editor, I would use that, but I only have `Array` and `Dictionary` to choose from.)

---

More details: I'm going to be looking up by the primary representation of the genre, thus the outer data structure in the `plist` has to be a dictionary.

But then for the synonyms, the only operation necessary is to enumerate them using a block.

So either an array or a dictionary will do. However, I'm concerned that using an array will imply an order that doesn't have any semantic meaning. On the other hand, is it a common occurrence to have dictionaries in `plist`s that don't have a corresponding value?

---

Editing again to respond to Josh's comments:

I like your idea of converting into an NSSet after reading in the `plist`. However, I could still do that with a dictionary, right? So not sure why an array is the obvious choice.

If someone else edits the plist, they might think there's a meaning to the order, when in reality, the ordering is arbitrary.

---

Surprised no-one has defended using a dictionary instead of an array. Is there a reason a dictionary shouldn't be used in a `plist` for this purpose?

Comment: You can always convert the array to a set after reading.

Comment: Thanks everyone--ended up going with an Array. It makes the code and data easiest to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about order, then the arbitrary order you get from building an array is equivalent to the arbitrary order you'd get by using a set. You can also very easily convert an array in a plist to an `NSSet` after reading it back: [`+[NSSet setWithArray:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CIHDCJGB)

So use an array.

Comment: I think you put it best. People don't expect a dictionary to be used like this--an array is most straightforward. Also easy conversion to NSSet is nice. Accept.

Comment: Yes, if you don't have a mapping, then using a dictionary would be inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use an array, since you say there's no corresponding key for a dictionary entry.

At the same time, if you're typing in a large number of entries into plist files (www), your fingers may get tired from dealing with the raw XML or plist editor stuff.  You might want to consider a different way to save your synonyms?

Comment: +1 because the plist editor is a pain. And I think I am going to end up automating the initial creation of the plist. So thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: CoffeeScript made generating the xml easy, and used [this site](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-formatter.html) to validate when Xcode complained. I probably would have muddled through doing it by hand, so thanks again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `NSArray` if lookup by item is not needed. If lookup is needed use an `NSDictionary`.