# How to read a localized plist as Dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, localization, plist

How can I read a localised plist as dictionary? This felt promising …

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LocalizedDictionary", ofType: "plist", inDirectory: ???, forLocalization: "en") {
        localizedDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        return localizedDictionary
}
```

But I apparently I had issues getting right path for the *inDirectory* parameter. Is this the right approach?

How do I get the localised version of a plist file as Dictionary?

Note: I am not using NSLocalizedString as I had issues without switching languages while the app is running.

Comment: So what does your directory structure look like.  Assuming you have an en.lproj.  Need more info to be helpful.  Also, are you sure your plist root node is not an array.  It can be an array or a dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521213/xcode-4-6-localization-within-plist-file

Comment: @mike.c It's not a duplicate although the question was similar. But the accepted answer there points to a completely different solution of not using the localised plist as such and also focusses on `NSLocalizedString` to access single strings (instead of receiving a whole localised dictionary). So unfortunately that wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's something that should help.**

Create a NSDictionary class extension like this.
It can be tweaked and adapted to your needs ( to load 'strings' dictionaries for exemple, or passing the locale in a parameter… )

```
@implementation NSDictionary (NSDictionary_Extras)

+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    NSDictionary    *dict = NULL;
    NSURL           *dictURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"plist"];

    if (dictURL) {
        dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:dictURL];
    }

    return dict;
}

+(NSDictionary*)localizedDictionaryWithName:(NSString*)name
{
    NSDictionary    *localizedDict = NULL;
    NSString        *localizationName = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL           *localizedDictURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"plist" subdirectory:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.lproj",localizationName]];
    // If resource doe not exist, we try at root ( resource must have a 'base' localization, or not being localized )
    if (!localizedDictURL) {
        localizedDictURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"plist"];
    }

    if (localizedDictURL) {
        localizedDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:localizedDictURL];
    } 

    return localizedDict;
}

@end
```

Then you simply load a plist using :

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithName:@"myDict"]
```

Or a localized plist with

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary localizedDictionaryWithName:@"myDict"].
```

I import this extra in all my projects.

Comment: I guess it can be easily swifted ;)

Answer (score -1):

**You don't need to change any code.**

xCode's resource localisation is neat and can frequently be completely transparent to you. You just ask the main bundle for resource urls as normal and load from them. `NSBundle` performs any mapping required to give you localised resources.

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.ibabbleon.com/iphone_app_localization.html) that got me going. It's a little out of date, but none of the significant details have changed.